# Long.parseLong("+2013") throws NumberFormatException

Tags: android, numberformatexception

I'm trying to get an external Java library to work with Android but its throwing errors while working with dates.

I've narrowed it down to this line:

```
Long year = Long.parseLong("+2013");
```

which throws a

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "+2013"
```

However, the code is valid and working in a pure Java application. Why does `Long.parseLong()` works differently in an Android app?

[Android's documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29) states that '+' Ascii signs are recognized:

> ```
> public static long parseLong (String string)
> ```
>
> Parses the specified string as a signed decimal long value. The ASCII characters - ('-') and + ('+') are recognized as the minus and plus signs.

Comment: Does it say the same for **-2013** as well?

Comment: Have you tried with `long year = Long.parseLong("+2013");`?

Comment: @hoomi I tested with both primitive `long` and object `Long` with both **+2013** and **-2013**, it didn't throw an exception. Weird.

Comment: I've tested it and it is working fine. Could you provide some more informations? (Java Version for example, I'm not sure what might cause this).

Comment: -2013 is working fine.
I'm using jdk1.8.0_73 with android studio 1.5.1

Comment: @jinang I am using Android Studio 1.5.1 and jdk1.7.0_80 64 bit and it's working fine.

Comment: Well.. OK... that is pretty strange.... Could you post the implementation of the parseLong function?

Comment: @oberflansch Well it looks like this for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/AJsZc.png

Comment: I've got exactly the same.... It seems to be some dark magic :/

Comment: @oberflansch Umm, I am not the one with the issue. I just tested it for OP on my machine and android device. @jinang Please post your `parseLong()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone! Managed to find out the problem.

It seems that API 17: Android 4.2 (Jelly Bean) is causing issues. The API doesn't handle the '+' sign in the parseLong() correctly.

Solved it changing the compile SDK to API 21 and later.

**API 20 parseLong()**

```
    /**
 * Parses the specified string as a signed long value using the specified
 * radix. The ASCII character \u002d ('-') is recognized as the minus sign.
 *
 * @param string
 *            the string representation of a long value.
 * @param radix
 *            the radix to use when parsing.
 * @return the primitive long value represented by {@code string} using
 *         {@code radix}.
 * @throws NumberFormatException
 *             if {@code string} cannot be parsed as a long value, or
 *             {@code radix < Character.MIN_RADIX ||
 *             radix > Character.MAX_RADIX}.
 */
public static long parseLong(String string, int radix) throws NumberFormatException {
    if (radix < Character.MIN_RADIX || radix > Character.MAX_RADIX) {
        throw new NumberFormatException("Invalid radix: " + radix);
    }
    if (string == null) {
        throw invalidLong(string);
    }
    int length = string.length(), i = 0;
    if (length == 0) {
        throw invalidLong(string);
    }
    boolean negative = string.charAt(i) == '-';
    if (negative && ++i == length) {
        throw invalidLong(string);
    }

    return parse(string, i, radix, negative);
}
```

**API 21 parseLong()**

```
    /**
 * Parses the specified string as a signed long value using the specified
 * radix. The ASCII characters \u002d ('-') and \u002b ('+') are recognized
 * as the minus and plus signs.
 *
 * @param string
 *            the string representation of a long value.
 * @param radix
 *            the radix to use when parsing.
 * @return the primitive long value represented by {@code string} using
 *         {@code radix}.
 * @throws NumberFormatException
 *             if {@code string} cannot be parsed as a long value, or
 *             {@code radix < Character.MIN_RADIX ||
 *             radix > Character.MAX_RADIX}.
 */
public static long parseLong(String string, int radix) throws NumberFormatException {
    if (radix < Character.MIN_RADIX || radix > Character.MAX_RADIX) {
        throw new NumberFormatException("Invalid radix: " + radix);
    }
    if (string == null || string.isEmpty()) {
        throw invalidLong(string);
    }
    char firstChar = string.charAt(0);
    int firstDigitIndex = (firstChar == '-' || firstChar == '+') ? 1 : 0;
    if (firstDigitIndex == string.length()) {
        throw invalidLong(string);
    }

    return parse(string, firstDigitIndex, radix, firstChar == '-');
}
```

Comment: That's weird. Sadly I don't have a 4.2 device to test this out. Anyways, glad your problem is solved!